# How to open a panel/form on the click of a link in Extjs?

Tags: extjs

I would like to know how I can open a panel/form on the click of a hyperlink which is in another panel in ExtJS.

Comment: [Saki's ExtJS Examples](http://examples.extjs.eu) -> Application Design -> Components Communication -> Run Example/Javascript source

Comment: That's a good start to get a grasp about the idea, but note that he's using Ext 2.3.0 (an older version of the framework) defining and creating objects is slightly different in the newer versions (ExtJS 4.x)

Comment: Yep, you are right. Saki is using the deprecated function Ext.extend.

Answer (score 2):

Define 'open'. When you say open I think of a window rather than a panel or form. Panels or forms can be created. You'r not very clear in what you want exactly.

You can render it to the body like this:

```
var panel = Ext.create('yourpanel', { renderTo: Ext.getBody() });
```

Or add it to another container eg:

```
var panel = Ext.create('yourpanel');
Ext.getCmp('id_of_somecontainer').add(panel);
```

PS If the issue is how to execute javascript from a link, try using:

```
<a herf="javascript:somefunction();">some link</a>
```

Comment: Yes I meant creating a panel

Answer (score 2):

You can add panel like -

```
Ext.get('test_link').on('click', function(){
    var panel = Ext.create('yourpanel');
    Ext.getCmp('target_panel').add(panel);
});
```

Comment: How to open file dailog in extjs?